# Why this LST code for Landsat 7 is not working?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, land-surface-temperature

I am trying to calculate LST from landsat 7, Band ST_B6, using the following code
https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e6c7e6060b8e658c9985d4f4f05f30f
imagen.multiply is not a function;is not a function`. I am unable to find the reason.

What is the possible solution?

```
enter code here
// cloudmask for SR data
function SR(image) {
var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');


 var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3)
.or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4))
return image.updateMask(mask.not());};
//Collection 2 SR data
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')
  .filterDate('2016-09-01', '2016-09-30').filterBounds(geometry).map(SR);
// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
var thermalBand = 
return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
.addBands(thermalBand, null, true);}
var data = dataset.map(applyScaleFactors);
var visualization = {
 bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'],
min: 0.0,
min: 0.0,
};
Map.setCenter(113.3921, 2.411, 8);
Map.addLayer(data, visualization, 'True Color (321) Sr');
var M1 = function(Imagen,tau,Lup,Ldown,epsilon) {
var imagen = data.select('ST_B6').geometry;
//De niveles digitales a radiancia
 var gain = 0.03720499947667122;
var offset = 3.1628000736236572;
 var L_lambda = imagen.multiply(gain).add(offset);
var L_corr = L_lambda.subtract(Lup).subtract(tau*Ldown*(1-epsilon))
  .divide(epsilon*tau);
var K1 = 666.0900268554688;
var K2 = 1282.7099609375;
var SST = L_corr.pow(ee.Image(-1)).multiply(K1).add(1).log()
.pow(ee.Image(-1)).multiply(K2).subtract(273.15);
var meanReducer = ee.Reducer.mean();
 var prom_SST = SST.reduceRegion(meanReducer);
return prom_SST;};
return prom_SST;
var coleccion = data;
var WST = ee.Number(ee.Image(M1(coleccion.get(1)).select('ST_B6').clip(geometry),5.20,0.31,7.43,epsilon).values().get(0));
print(WST);
Map.addLayer(WST);
```

Comment: I add the code. Could you please check?

Answer (score 1):

The error will be from here:

```js
var imagen = data.select('ST_B6').geometry
```

This line doesn't make sense. If you meant to get the bounds of the image then you need to write `.geometry()` instead of `.geometry`. But, your following code `imagen.multiply(gain).add(offset)` implies that you are expecting an image, so probably you should remove `.geometry` entirely.

Comment: I did. But no result.